# Jquery Heat Map Coloring

Tags: jquery, heatmap

I have a table with every column having values between -100 to +100.
I want to color them with all element below zero to -100 going from white to dark red.
and the ones from zero to +100 with colors from white to dark green.

Any suggestion on how I can brew the colors using JQuery?

I am having trouble with selectors .. so best if I can just do a set background css via jquery

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501505/how-to-generate-a-color-sequence-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

With a function that can calculate a color component at a point between two values, you can use the `rgb(r,g,b)` color syntax in CSS to set the background color:

```
function morph(start, stop, point) {
  return Math.round(stop - start) * point / 100 + start);
}

$('td').each(function(){
  var value = parseInt($(this).text());
  var color;
  if (value < 0) {
    color = morph(255,100,-value) + ',' + morph(255,0,-value) + ',' + morph(255,0,-value);
  } else {
    color = morph(255,0,value) + ',' + morph(255,50,value) + ',' + morph(255,0,value);
  }
  $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(' + color + ')');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Might I suggest my own jQuery plugin?

[jQuery Hottie](https://github.com/DLarsen/jquery-hottie) makes it easy to take normal markup and add a background color like so:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr><td>-100</td><td>50</td><td>-30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>100</td><td>0</td><td>-30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>750</td><td>-50</td><td>40</td></tr>
</table>
```

And in JS:

```
$("#myTable td").hottie({
    colorArray : [ 
        "#F8696B", // highest value
        "#FFFFFF",
        "#63BE7B"  // lowest value
        // add as many colors as you like...
    ]
});
```

Results:

[image: JSFiddle]

See this example live in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8vX/1/)

Comment: This is fantastic and worked great for a project I was working on. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the [HeatColor](http://www.jnathanson.com/blog/client/jquery/heatcolor/) jQuery plugin.  However, be warned that the precise color sequence you want may not be available.

A [good tutorial](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-tutorial-create-a-flexible-data-heat-map/) on rolling your own can be found at designchemical.com.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function on any table that needs to have different levels of green (highest value) and red (lowest value).

(In this example td values are floating number representing percentages - like 0.941 for 94.1%):

```
function heatmap()
{
    var heat_max = 0;
    var heat_min = 100;

    //loop through table cells to find min and max values
    $('table#heatmap').find('td').each(function() 
    {
        var cell_val = Math.round(parseFloat($(this).text()) * 1000) / 10;

        if(cell_val > heat_max) { heat_max = cell_val;}
        if(cell_val < heat_min) { heat_min = cell_val;}
    });

    //reloop through table cells and apply background color
    $('table#heatmap').find('td').each(function()
    {
        var cell_val = Math.round(parseFloat($(this).text()) * 1000) / 10;

        var color_pct = (cell_val - heat_min)  / (heat_max - heat_min);
        var color_int = 2 * 255 * color_pct;

        var r = 255, g = 255;
        if(color_int <= 255) { g = color_int;        } 
                       else  { r =  510 - color_int; }

        var bg_color = 'rgba('+r+', '+g+', 50, 0.2)';

        $(this).css({'backgroundColor' : bg_color});
    });

}
```